# When consumer motherboards state they "support ECC", do they mean "as fully as server boards", or only somewhat?

Tags: memory, motherboard, specifications, ecc

A number of modern consumer boards state they "support ECC" when used with RDIMMs + Xeon, for example, [this ASROCK X99 board](http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/X99%20Extreme4/).

But the documentation never seems to say (for any brand, not just this one) the extent of support. Usually on a server board, 1 bit correct, 2 bits detect is typical.

(I know support depends on the CPU + chipset, I'm not sure to what extent it depends on the BIOS and baseboard, probably depends entirely on those as well.)

To be clear, I'm not interested in additional server board *RAM features* such as lockstep/sparing/mirroring, just error detection/correction.)

Can I actually tell before buying (or at a pinch, afterwards by testing), for a consumer board like this - either from specs I'm not seeing, or details of the hardware, or at a last resort by running something like Memtest86, whether ECC RDIMM support is as full and as capable as it would be for a server grade board where the nature of ECC support is more explicitly stated? And for example whether it handles 1 bit errors only, or 1+2 bit errors?

Comment: The motherboard in question supports ECC RDIMM provided you use a Xeon processor.  A motherboard must specifically indicate it supports ECC memory.

Comment: From my understanding, the ECC specs are more of a hardware spec than software "feature" spec meaning I would suspect all the different types of memory would be full featured because of the nature of the spec.

Comment: @Ramhound - but the question is "how sure can I be, about to what extent it's supporting detect / detect+correct, and what is the easiest way to be sure how completely implemented it is on the board"? This info isn't usually stated explicitly in boards that say they handle ECC with the right CPU/DIMMs, but which aren't primarily targeted at server markets. It might be 100% supported.... but maybe only partial (detect but not correct? correct 1 bit, no detect on 2 bits?) for all I can be sure of it. That's the nub of the Q.

Comment: @Damon - My guess is otherwise. I suspect the BIOS has to recognise and manage ECC errors, and the baseboard is configured what to handle and how to handle it, via its hardware design and the bios, both of which the manufacturer can control and make final decisions on. That's firmware and baseboard design not just CPU and DIMM modules. So I'm not at all sure one can make that assumption safely (even though it might often be true)